# Beautiful Soup scrape table with table breaks

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a [table](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/prices.php) into a dataframe. My attempt only returns the table name and not the data within rows for each region.

This is what i have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests

url = 'https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/prices.php'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4(r.text, "html.parser")

table_regions = soup.find('table', {'class': "t4"})
regions = table_regions.find_all('tr')

for row in regions:
    print row
```

ideal outcome i'd like to get:

```
region         | price   
---------------|-------
new england    | 2.59
new york city  | 2.52
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your html response (soup) you will see that the table tag you get in this line `table_regions = soup.find('table', {'class': "t4"})` its closed up before the rows that contain the information you need (the ones that contain the td's with the class names: up dn d1 and s1.
So how about using the raw td tags like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/prices.php'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4(r.text, "html.parser")

a = soup.find_all('tr')
rows = []
subel = []

for tr in a[42:50]:
    b = tr.find_all('td')
    for td in b:
        subel.append(td.string)
    rows.append(subel)
    subel = []

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Region','Price_1', 'Percent_change_1', 'Price_2', 'Percent_change_2', 'Spark Spread'])
```

Notice that I use just the `a[42:50]` slice of the results because a contains  all the td's of the website. You can use the rest too if you need to.

Comment: thanks a lot for the guidance. made a minor tweak to the row index to capture all records `a[40:50]` :)